# Is it possible to link items (user stories, etc.) in one Azure Board to another?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We are setting up a new Azure Devops Board to track all of our work. Some of the projects being tracked are in a different board managed by a different team (under a different Organization).

We would like to be able to link these other Stories, Features, etc. to be linked to our board too so that we only need to write the update in one place.

I know it is possible to create a hyperlink directly to the existing Board, but not all of the users (e.g. leadership team) on the new board will have access.

So is it possible to somehow write an update in one place and have it update on another Board too?

We have created a hyperlink for testing purposes but users that didn't have rights to the existing Board were unable to access it, which is perfectly expected. I haven't found any other way to link the data from one Board to another.

Comment: ..What have you tried doing? What errors are being caused? You need to include this stuff so we are able to answer your question properly.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I think I did answer all of your questions. I have tried creating a hyperlink to the stories in the other board and I could see that correctly, but because I didn't have access to the other board, I wasn't able to see it. There is no error other than me not having permissions, which is understandable. My query is whether it is possible to set some other more dynamic link set up so that we could update something in our board and this would automatically update the other, "linked" target story. I hope this makes sense. This is more a "how to" question and not an error per se.

Comment: I understand you would expect an automated workflow to **synchronize** certain fields of the work items from 2 boards. What type of link and how you setup the link between the two work items? I am thinking to use API for synchronization, but at least we need to know how the two work items know each other. And by the way, two boards are from two different Azure DevOps Organizations right?

Comment: @AlvinZhao yes, that's exactly what we would need but I don't really know where to start. We are new at this :)  Yes, the two boards are from different organizations, exactly.

Comment: I understand your expectation, but as of now there is no out-of-box feature to do so. Let's assume we have a `User Story A` in `Org1` as the source and as soon as the source is updated, how the automated workflow gets to the which target work item in `Org2` is to be synchronized? The mapping information has to be restored **somewhere manually first**. I wonder if you have already set and how you have set such mapping information for both source and target items to know each other.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Alvin. You have understood my question perfectly. We currently have no such mapping set up because we don't know how to do this. Would you suggest using an API to do this? If it helps, we also have access to Azure Data Factory, PowerBI Automate, PowerApps...

Comment: Hi Chris, I am thinking of using nested feature of Azure DevOps pipeline as the automated workflow. It works and I am trying to optimize it. Will come back to you shortly. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description to synchronize certain fields of work items between 2 boards from 2 Azure DevOps organizations, I am afraid there is no out-of-box feature as of now. As discussed, to customize an automated workflow for such requirement, the mapping information between the two WITs has to be restored **somewhere manually first**, so that the workflow is aware which WIT in the target organization should be updated when the WIT in the source organization is modified.

Since the pipeline feature of Azure DevOps itself is an automation tool and we can use a custom field in the WIT to restore the mapping information, I have figured out a custom workflow within Azure DevOps. Let's assume we need to synchronize the two WITs namely `UserStory1 of ProjectA from OrgA` (as the source WIT) and `UserStory2 of ProjectB from OrgB` (as the target WIT). Here is the design.

**Prerequisites and optimizations taken into consideration**

- To trigger the pipeline when `UserStory1 of ProjectA from OrgA` is updated, we can **subscribe** `WIT Update` [Web Hook event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) in `ProjectA` and **monitor** the event from source Project/org in a pipeline of `ProjectB` by [Web Hook resource in YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-webhooks-resource);
- To update `UserStory2 of ProjectB from OrgB` with the information extracted from Web Hook payload, we can call this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) in `InvokeRESTAPI@1` pipeline task; this task is an [agentless job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs) supported task, which doesn't request to use a pipeline agent machine; hence, it can save time for agent assignment and won't cause any agent job to be pending in the queue of an agent pool, either; (the simple job only takes **1-2** seconds to complete;)
- Per the authentication of the API request, we can use `$(System.AccessToken)` of the pipeline service account, which can not only avoid the risk of Personal Access Tokens leakage, but is also less prone to getting throttled by [Rate usage limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops);

**Steps to generate a sample workflow**

1. Create [custom fields in inheritance process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops) for WITs in both source and target organizations to track the mapping WIT IDs;
   [image]
2. Create an `Incoming WebHook` service connection in the **target** organization (`OrgB` in this sample) and keep notes of the **Web Hook name** (`ADOWebHookWIT`) and **service connection name** (`ADOWebHookWITSvcCnn`);
   [image]
3. Generate the Web Hook URL and **subscribe** the **WIT update** event in the **source** organization (`ProjectA` in `OrgA`);

   ```
   https://dev.azure.com/{Target OrgName (OrgB)}/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/{Web Hook Name (ADOWebHookWIT)}?api-version=6.0-preview
   ```

   [image]
4. Create `Generic` service connection like below in `ProjectB` for the pipeline task `InvokeRESTAPI@1`;
   [image]
5. Create a new YAML pipeline in `ProjectB` with the `.yml` file contents below to monitor the Web Hook events sent from `OrgA`; make sure the pipeline service account is granted permission to edit work items in the expected area path (Edit the `Security` of **project root** node in my case);

```
trigger: none

resources:
  webhooks:
  # WIT update Web Hook subscription - sent from OrgA to https://dev.azure.com/OrgB/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/ADOWebHookWIT?api-version=6.0-preview
  - webhook: ADOWebHookWIT
    connection: ADOWebHookWITSvcCnn # Web Hook service connection name

variables:
  # Retrieve target work item Id in OrgB from the triggering Web Hook payload sent from OrgA
  targetWITId: ${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['Custom.MappedWITIDInTargetOrg'] }}
  orgB: ${{ split(variables['System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri'], '/')[5] }} # Split OrgB's name from $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)

jobs:
- job: Synchronization
  displayName: Update workitem with id of ${{ variables.targetWITId }} in ${{variables['System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri']}}
  pool: server # This is an agentless job
  steps:
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
      serviceConnection: 'AzureDevOpsServices' # Generic service connection name
      method: 'PATCH'
      # Authenticate against $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service account
      headers: |
        {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)',
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json-patch+json'
        }
      body: |
        [
          {
              'op' : 'add',
              'path' : '/fields/System.State',
              'value' : '${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['System.State'] }}'
          },
          {
              'op' : 'add',
              'path' : '/fields/System.Description',
              'value' : '${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['System.Description'] }}'
          },
          {
              'op' : 'add',
              'path' : '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints',
              'value' : '${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints'] }}'
          },
          {
              'op' : 'add',
              'path' : '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority',
              'value' : '${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority'] }}'
          },
          {
              'op' : 'add',
              'path' : '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Risk',
              'value' : '${{ parameters.ADOWebHookWIT.resource.revision.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Risk'] }}'
          }
        ]
      urlSuffix: '$(OrgB)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/workitems/$(targetWITId)?api-version=7.2-preview.3' # Construct the complete URL with pipeline predefined variables
      waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

[image]
6. As soon as I edited the `UserStory1 of ProjectA from OrgA`, the pipeline of `OrgB` received the WIT update event sent from `OrgA` and then pipeline was automatically triggered and updated `UserStory2 of ProjectB from OrgB` (`#615`) via API with the information transferred in the payload; we can see the organization name and project name information were not restored in each WIT, as the values were retrieved by the pipeline predefined variables `System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri` and `System.TeamProject`. Therefore, this benefits us from creating additional custom fields, but requires that the pipeline and the target work item are from the same project.
[image]
[image]

If you would like to synchronize more fields, you can modify the request body accordingly. Hope the sample workflow for your reference may help.